# Neural Network doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I've been creating my own neural network by following a book called "Make Your Own Neural Network" by Tariq Rashid. After some theory, the book explains an example written in Python. Since I'm not into Python that much I tried implementing it in C++.
And yes, I did try existing libraries. But now I'd like to implement my own architecture I can tweak as I wish and use them with my Qt and AR projects.

Feeding forward the signals works as expected. I used the same sample values as given in the book and it all seems to be working fine. 
The back-propagation however fails at solving the XOR problem. The output value is almost always the same. It's just a bit bigger when both input values are 0.0. The weights appear unusually big to me (often bigger than 7.0. Not sure if that's normal). 
Indexing through all layers and transposing those that need to be, also works fine since otherwise, I'd get out of bounds errors.
The project consists of a namespace containing all matrix calculations and the NeuralNetwork class.

Perhaps someone knows what's causing the issue in my code.
Thanks

(EDIT: If you want to compile and run it on your own you can [get the source from my Git repository](https://github.com/CosmoCortney/NeuralNetwork-in-CPP))

AnnMaths.cpp

```
#include "AnnMaths.h"

vector<vector<double>> AnnMaths::transpose(vector<vector<double>>& x)
{
    vector<vector<double>> y;

    for (int col = 0; col < x[0].size(); ++col)
    {
        y.push_back(vector<double>());
        for (int row = 0; row < x.size(); ++row)
        {
            y[col].push_back(x[row][col]);
        }
    }

    return y;
}

vector<vector<double>> AnnMaths::multiply(vector<vector<double>>& x, vector<vector<double>>& y, bool useSigmoid)
{
    vector<vector<double>> z;

    for (int row = 0; row < x.size(); row++)
    {
        z.push_back(vector<double>());
        for (int col = 0; col < y[0].size(); col++)
        {
            z[row].push_back(0);
            for (int inner = 0; inner < x[0].size(); inner++)
            {
                z[row][col] += x[row][inner] * y[inner][col];
            }
            if (useSigmoid) { z[row][col] = sigmoid(z[row][col]); }
        }
    }

    return z;
}

vector<vector<double>> AnnMaths::getOutputErrors(vector<vector<double>>& targets, vector<vector<double>>& output)
{
    vector<vector<double>> errors;

    for (int neuron = 0; neuron < targets.size(); ++neuron)
    {
        errors.push_back(vector<double>());
        errors[neuron].push_back(/*pow(*/targets[neuron][0] - output[neuron][0]/*, 2)*/);
    }

    return errors;
}

vector<vector<double>> AnnMaths::getHiddenErrors(vector<vector<double>>& weightsT, vector<vector<double>>& errors)
{
    vector<vector<double>> results = multiply(weightsT, errors);
    return results;
}

vector<vector<double>> AnnMaths::applyErrors(vector<vector<double>>& errors, vector<vector<double>>& output)
{
    vector<vector<double>> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < errors.size(); ++i)
    {
        results.push_back(vector<double>());
        results[i].push_back(errors[i][0] * output[i][0] * (1.0 - output[i][0]));
    }

    return results;
}

vector<vector<double>> AnnMaths::applyLearnrate(vector<vector<double>>& x, double lr)
{
    vector<vector<double>> results;

    for (int row = 0; row < x.size(); ++row)
    {
        results.push_back(vector<double>());
        for (int col = 0; col < x[0].size(); ++col)
        {
            results[row].push_back(x[row][col] * lr);
        }
    }

    return results;
}

vector<vector<double>> AnnMaths::add(vector<vector<double>>& x, vector<vector<double>>& y)
{
    vector<vector<double>> results;

    for (int row = 0; row < x.size(); ++row)
    {
        results.push_back(vector<double>());
        for (int col = 0; col < x[0].size(); ++col)
        {
            results[row].push_back(x[row][col] + y[row][col]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}

double AnnMaths::sigmoid(double val)
{
    return 1 / (1 + pow(E, -val));
}

double AnnMaths::randomVal()
{
    return ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX) -0.5);
}
```

NeuralNetwork.cpp

```
#include "NeuralNetwork.h"

NeuralNetwork::NeuralNetwork(vector<int>& topology, vector<vector<double>>& input, vector<vector<double>>& targets, double lr)
{
    this->topology = topology;
    this->layers.clear();
    this->weights.clear();
    this->targets.clear();
    this->targets = targets;
    this->layers.resize(topology.size());
    this->errors.resize(this->layers.size());
    this->weights.resize(topology.size()-1);
    this->learnrate = lr;

    for (int layer = 0; layer < topology.size(); ++layer)
    {
        if (layer == 0)
        {
            this->layers[layer].push_back(vector<double>());
            this->layers[layer] = input;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int neuron = 0; neuron < topology[layer]; ++neuron)
            {
                this->layers[layer].push_back(vector<double>());
                this->layers[layer][neuron].push_back(/*AnnMaths::randomVal()*/0.0);
            }
        }

        if (layer < (topology.size() - 1))
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < topology[layer+1]; ++row)
            {
                this->weights[layer].push_back(vector<double>());
                for (int col = 0; col < topology[layer]; ++col)
                {
                    this->weights[layer][row].push_back(AnnMaths::randomVal());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this->errors = this->layers;
}

void NeuralNetwork::feedForward()
{
    for (int layer = 0; layer < weights.size(); ++layer)
    {
        layers[layer + 1] = AnnMaths::multiply(weights[layer], layers[layer], true);
    }
}

void NeuralNetwork::setErrors()
{
    for (int layer = layers.size() - 1; layer >= 0; --layer)
    {
        if (layer == layers.size() - 1)
        {
            this->errors[layer] = AnnMaths::getOutputErrors(this->targets, layers[layer]);
        }
        else
        {
            vector<vector<double>> weightsT = AnnMaths::transpose(this->weights[layer]);
            vector<vector<double>> tmpErrors = AnnMaths::multiply(weightsT, this->errors[layer+1]);
            this->errors[layer] = tmpErrors;
        }
    }
}

void NeuralNetwork::setInput(vector<vector<double>>& input)
{
    this->layers[0] = input;
}

void NeuralNetwork::setTargets(vector<vector<double>>& target)
{
    this->targets = targets;
}

void NeuralNetwork::backPropagation()
{
    setErrors(); //compute all errors

    for (int layer = layers.size() - 2; layer >= 0; --layer)
    {
        vector<vector<double>> prevOutputT = AnnMaths::transpose(layers[layer]); //get the transposed output of the previous layer
        vector<vector<double>> appliedErrors = AnnMaths::applyErrors(this->errors[layer+1], layers[layer+1]); //apply errors to output of next layer
        vector<vector<double>> deltaWeights = AnnMaths::multiply(appliedErrors, prevOutputT); //compute delta of weights by multiplying the applied output with the previous output
        deltaWeights = AnnMaths::applyLearnrate(deltaWeights, learnrate); //add learning rate to delta weights
        weights[layer] = AnnMaths::add(deltaWeights, weights[layer]); //add delta weights to the weights
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include"AnnMaths.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include"NeuralNetwork.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> input;
    input.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    input.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    input.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    input.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    input[0].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[0].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[0][0].push_back(0.0);
    input[0][1].push_back(0.0);
    input[1].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[1].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[1][0].push_back(1.0);
    input[1][1].push_back(0.0);
    input[2].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[2].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[2][0].push_back(0.0);
    input[2][1].push_back(1.0);
    input[3].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[3].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    input[3][0].push_back(1.0);
    input[3][1].push_back(1.0);

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> targets;
    targets.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    targets.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    targets.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    targets.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>());
    targets[0].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    targets[0][0].push_back(0.0);
    targets[1].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    targets[1][0].push_back(1.0);
    targets[2].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    targets[2][0].push_back(1.0);
    targets[3].push_back(std::vector<double>());
    targets[3][0].push_back(0.0);

    std::vector<int> topology;
    topology.push_back(input[0].size());
    topology.push_back(3);
    topology.push_back(targets[0].size());

    NeuralNetwork nn(topology, input[0], targets[0], 0.3);

    for (struct { int i = 0; int count = 0; } x; x.i < 10000; ++x.i, ++x.count)
    {
        if (x.count == 4) { x.count = 0; }
        nn.setInput(input[x.count]);
        nn.setTargets(targets[x.count]);

        nn.feedForward();
        nn.backPropagation();

        if (x.i % 51 == 0 )
        {
            nn.printInput();
            nn.printOutput();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For better visibility I did not include test and print functions.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code with a debugger?

Comment: Where should I start debugging or set breakpoints? In this case, I'm not certain how a debugger could help me when no exception occurs

Comment: You could set a breakpoint at `nn.backPropagation();` and go into the method.

Comment: Okay, I did that. What should examine there now?

Comment: You said that that `feedForward` works and `backPropagation` yields wrong values. So you know that at some point something unexpected happens. Now you have to find the first line of code that behaves different than you expect.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what values to be expected. The book does not show any sample values for an entire back-propagation process in detail